# Content text area empty on first send using Tinymce text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I have never come across this before which is why I have come to see if anyone can shed some light on why or what is causing this.

Basically I am calling in Tinymce editor using the following html javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "#content",
            theme: "modern",
            plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste imagetools Customlayouts Customshortcodes, autoresize responsivefilemanager"
            ],
            toolbar: "Customlayouts Customshortcodes | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | link responsivefilemanager image media | code fullscreen",
            image_advtab: true ,
            relative_urls: false,
            external_filemanager_path:"http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/Libs/filemanager/",
            filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
            external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/Libs/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
        });
    });
</script>       
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="content" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Page Content</label>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the issue is that on the first time you submit the form it sends nothing which can be seen here:

```
'type' => string 'sendform' (length=8)
  'name' => string '' (length=0)
  'title' => string '' (length=0)
  'slug' => string '' (length=0)
  'tags' => string '' (length=0)
  'description' => string '' (length=0)
  'content' => string '' (length=0)
  'islive' => string 'false' (length=5)
```

But if I click the submit button again without doing anything it then sends the content like shown here:

```
  'type' => string 'sendform' (length=8)
  'name' => string '' (length=0)
  'title' => string '' (length=0)
  'slug' => string '' (length=0)
  'tags' => string '' (length=0)
  'description' => string '' (length=0)
  'content' => string '<p>sdfsdfsdf</p>' (length=16)
  'islive' => string 'false' (length=5)
```

I am using ajax to send the form which is most likely the issue.
Here is my jquery submit:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#addnewpage').on('submit', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Applications/Controllers/Pages/ajax-pages.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){

                if(data === 'success'){ 

                    window.location.href = "/Control-Panel/Pages/Manage/?success=added";

                } else {

                    $('#ubl-fail').slideUp(300);
                    $('#ubl-fail').html(data);
                    $('#ubl-fail').delay(350).slideDown(300);
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

                }

            }           
        });

    });
});
```

I do not understand why this is happening I am checking my console log to see if any errors arise but there are none.
I have no errors within the html or php side of it also.
Especially considering at the moment on the php side I am simply doing this:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Anyway that is the issue and I would be very thankful if anyone could shed some light on why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution meanwhile?

Comment: @elMeroMero no I never did solve this, I had to send it using normal form and not ajax in the end which was a little bit annoying to say the least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. It turned out all I had to do was adding tinyMCE.triggerSave() before submitting.

```
$('#addnewpage').on('submit', function(
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    $('form#document-form').submit();
});
```

Comment: This has worked for me thanks. As it turns out, the iframe shown on the textarea by TinyMCE is only an "appearance" shown in place of the original textarea, however, when we're going to send the data using AJAX, we have to tell it to pass these data back to the original textarea. What's so weird is that it was working fine for me even before I used this method, but then it stopped working and empty string was sent.

Answer (score -1):

Add this script...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({mode : "specific_textareas", editor_selector : "myTextEditor",    theme: "modern",    theme_advanced_fonts : "Andale Mono=andale mono,times; "+                "Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif; "+                "Arial Black=arial black,avant garde; "+                "Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino; "+                "Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif; "+                "Courier New=courier new,courier; "+                "Georgia=georgia,palatino; "+                "Helvetica=helvetica; "+                "Impact=impact,chicago; "+                "Symbol=symbol; "+                "Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; "+                "Terminal=terminal,monaco; "+                "Times New Roman=times new roman,times; "+                "Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva; "+                "Verdana=verdana,geneva; "+                "Webdings=webdings; "+                "Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats",    plugins: [        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"    ],    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",    toolbar2: "fontselect |  forecolor backcolor emoticons",    image_advtab: true,    templates: [        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}    ]});
</script>
```